# Nginx + Zend Framework: Htpasswd protect a module

Tags: php, zend-framework, nginx

I'm running nginx 1.1.19 on Ubuntu.
In my Zend Framework 1 project I want to htpasswd protect a specific module, say:

http://www.example.org/ <- accessible by everyone
http://www.example.org/protected <- protected by htpasswd file

I've set up the following nginx vhost config:

```
server {
 root /srv/www/example/public;
 index index.php;
 ...
 location ~ \.php$ {
 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
 include fastcgi_params;
 }
 ...
}
```

When I now add the following to protect /protected

```
  location ~ ^/protected/.+\.php$ {
      auth_basic "restricted";
      auth_basic_user_file  htpasswd/mypasswd;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      include   fastcgi_params;
    }
```

htpasswd is not applied. When I reduce the top line to `location ~^/protected/` I get an "Access denied.".

How can I make nginx executing php correctly (through /public/index.php, Zend Framework) but still protecting everything behind /protected/?

Comment: Don't mean to hijack your question, but is there a reason you need to use htpasswd and not built in auth / ACL?

Comment: thanks for you're answer. there are some internal reasons why we can't use auth/acl, that's why we're dealing with htpasswd. so thanks for the answer, but I'd appreciate a solution for htpasswd.